# How to use both node and relationship auto-index in cypher?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

i have a problem, Can you help me?

In my real neo4j2.1.3, there are hurge nodes and relationships. so i have to use auto-index for performance.

For example: The property key 'person_name', 'hotel_name' for node auto-index.  and 'inTime' for relationship auto-index.

Then, I create data:

```
create (:Person {person_name:'p1'})
create (:Person {person_name:'p2'})
create (:Hotel {hotel_name:'h1'} )
create (:Hotel {hotel_name:'h2'} )

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h1')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140520'}]->(h)

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h2')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140522'}]->(h)

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p2'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h1')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140510'}]->(h)
```

Next, I type this cypher:

```
start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),
      r=relationship:relationship_auto_index('inTime:[20140501 TO 20140530]')  
match (p)-[r]-(h) return p,r,h
```

I only want retrieve the relationship that 'p1' stay in. but the cypher above return relationships both p1 and p2. Why?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of use case I would not use autoindexes at all and I don't see a need for indexing the relationships either. The question you want to get answered is basicall "Give me the stays of person p1 in any hotel in timeframe t_min to t_max?".

Create a schema index to quickly look up the starting point, aka the person in question:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(person_name)
```

Your query would look like this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {person_name:"p1"})-[stay:STAY_IN]->(hotel)
WHERE stay.inTime>=t_min AND stay.inTime<=t_max
RETURN stay, hotel
```

Indexes in Neo4j should just be used to identify the start points of your query. Once you are in the graph just follow relationships and try to avoid subsequent index lookup, like the index search on relationships.

In your code the second index query would return all stays for any person in the given time frame. This is used in a cross product with `p`, that's why you got `p2` as well.

Comment: Hi, @Stefan Armbruster, thanks for your reply.
You see what i said. but my case is not so simple.
I have tried the schema index. but it does not support range query. and it does not support fuzzy search.  it only be used for exactly match. 
For example: If i have create 2 index for property keys 'person_name' and 'person_birthday' :
  create index ON :Person(person_name)
  create index ON :Person(person_birthday)
if i type these query:
    match (p:Person ) where p.person_name='Mike*' return p
    match (p:Person) where p.person_birthday > '19800501' return p
the schema index will not work.

Comment: Let's go back the question earlier in my real case, Consider this:
 If there are millons person nodes in neo4j db, and each node have also millons relationships to other.  so what should i do? 
   Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I'm quite sure that if you save your dates as integers and not strings, you can perform matches using ranges and it will use the index. `match (p:Person) where p.person_birthday > 19800501 return p`. As far as fuzzy search is concerned, I usually recommend using Elasticsearch. It will do a better job and let Neo4j do what it does best.

Comment: in this case you need to use auto indexes.

Comment: Thank you. @subvertallchris
Not long ago, I had a test:
match (p:Person) where p.person_birthday > 19800501205000 return p
There ars 5 millons nodes in neo4j. the cypher runs so slower.
Also if i use OR in WHERE clause, schema index will not work:
match (p:Person) where p.person_birthday = 19800501205000 OR p.person_name = 'Mike Toms' return p
schema index has many limitations, so i have to use auto index.

Comment: Hi, @Stefan Armbruster：
   I found a way to use both node and relationship index. but i don't know that this is ture:
      start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),
            r=relationship:relationship_auto_index('inTime:[20140501 TO 20140530]')  
      with p,r
      match (p)-[r]-(h) return p,r,h

Comment: If that's more efficient than looking up the user by index, following all relationships and filtering depends on your numbers. If your relationship index search returns only a few results it might be better. If the search range is large, the simple approach sketched might perform better.